# Is there a way to setup a site monitor on drupal?

Tags: 7

I have the current question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37712/ubercart-items-wont-add-to-cart-unless-cache-is-cleared. In order to try and narrow down what the issue is. I'm curious if there is a way to setup a sort of monitor or logs to be able to get some more insight as to what is going wrong. I know of the typical status reports, Log messages & server logs. But is there anything that might be able to give me more drupal related details?

Answer (score -1):

mysql and httpd logging on your server should help a bit.  turn them on (and adjust reporting levels) but make sure you don't fill up your disk with logs.  turn the logging level back down to something normal once you've looked for a while.